# Cannot Find Custom Module in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I created a little custom library to help make development a little easier for me. Below is the tscnfig and package.json file for this library.

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es6",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es6",                       /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    //"lib": [],                           /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": false,                        /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "declarationMap": false,                   /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": false,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    "removeComments": true,                   /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    "noEmitOnError": true,                    /* No output will be emited if there is an error in the input files. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": false,                   /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                 /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,              /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                     /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": false,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": false,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,           /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./tests"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fragment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A library",
  "main": "dist/fragment.js",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "dist/fragment.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "inspect:circular": "npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./"
  },
  "author": "PatrickLumenus",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  }
}
```

I then attempt to use this library in a project by importing it with the following

```
yarn add <path to the github repo>
```

So far, it all looks good. However, when I start using the library, as the following:

```
import { On } from 'fragment';
```

And, then run my application, I get the following error:

```
 Cannot find module 'fragment'.
```

In VScode, it is saying "Cannot find module "fragment" or its corresponding type declarations".

I did some digging into this, and it looks like I have followed all the requirements, including:

1. setting the "declaration" property to true in my tsconfig file.
2. setting the types property in my library's package.json file to "dist/fragment.d.ts" (see above)
3. compile the library with tsc (the dist output directory is actually included). And, it compiled with no errors.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

For reference here is the tsconfig and package.json for the test project that is using the library.

tsconfig for test project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ES6",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    "noEmitOnError": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

package.json for test project

```
{
  "name": "simple-chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "fragment": "https://github.com/path-to-repo.ggit"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node ./dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your path to the repo in package.json shows .ggit >> is it a mistake on the level of Stackoverflow or is it a real issue.

Comment: No. That’s just a placeholder so I don’t reveal my Repo URL. lol

Comment: ok, just one more thing, check if the package name in your remote PACKAGE is what you're trying to import.

Comment: You mean the package.json of the library in the github Repo? It should be. I even included it in the bottom code segment.

Comment: Gimme sometime, I'm trying to regenerate your issue in my machine.

Comment: Ok, so tried the same thing.
I have this package in my GIT and when I do yarn add https://Pathtorepo.git it installs it, and automatically adds it to my package.json as it should.

Afterward, I am able to import it in my ts file.

The issue must be in some sort of naming, or are you using ssh,
and if you're using ssh can you give me a closer example of how you used it in `yarn add` 

It must use the `ssh` protocol .. `ssh://github.com/username/yourrepo.git`

Comment: Nope. I’m not using SSH. I guess I’ll take a look again. The weird thing is, if I set my test project to “commons” it finds the package. But obviously that doesn’t work because it’s an ES6 package. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ooh! That seems weird, alright. Hope you find the reason behind this. :)

Comment: Yeah. I found it. I was just had to mess with my tsconfig file a bit... Sadly, I kinda don’t know what I changed. Lol. But, I’ll answer this once I have some time to replicate it.

Comment: Kudos :), That's great to hear.

and Yeah waiting for you to know, what exactly changed.


I believe it has something to do with, `
allowUMDglobalacess`